# Convert list counting repeated elements

Tags: scala

I'm trying to solve problem 13 from [here](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) using recursion, but I get an error (which I don't understand).

The problem is:

Given the following list `List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)`

I need to return repeated elements and count:

`List((4,'a), (1,'b), (2,'c), (2,'a), (1,'d), (4,'e))`

This is my code:

```
object P13 extends App  {

    val ls2 = List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)

    println(ls2)
    println(encodeDirect(ls2))

    def encodeDirect[A](ls: List[A]): List[(Int,A)] = ls match {
        case h :: tail => (ls.takeWhile( _ == h ).count(_), h)  +: encodeDirect (ls.dropWhile ( _ == h ) ) 
        case Nil => Nil
    }

}
```

This is the error:

```
P13.scala:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(Any, A)]
 required: List[(Int, A)]
        case h :: tail => (ls.takeWhile( _ == h ).count(_), h)  +: encodeDirect
(ls.dropWhile ( _ == h ) )
                                                                ^
one error found
```

Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is quite simple, you used `count` instead of `size`/`length`:

```
  def encodeDirect[A](ls: List[A]): List[(Int,A)] = ls match {
    case h :: tail => (ls.takeWhile( _ == h ).size, h)  +: encodeDirect (ls.dropWhile ( _ == h ) )
    case Nil => Nil
  }
```

`count` takes predicate and calculates the number of elements that match that predicate, while `size` just returns the length of the collection.

Just for fun, here is an alternative, that utilizes `span`, that breaks collection into prefix/suffix:

```
def encodeDirect[A](ls: List[A]): List[(Int,A)] =
   ls.headOption.map(h => ls.span(h == _)).toList
     .flatMap { case (pref, t) => (pref.size, pref.head) :: encodeDirect(t) }
```

Also it may be a good idea to rewrite this function in tail-recursive way, using results accumulator as an argument, as tail recursion is more efficient in scala.

Comment: shouldn't `count(_)` match all the predicates and be equivalent to `size` ?

Comment: @ps0604, actually, no. Predicate function in `count`  is `T => Boolean`, so you probably wanted `count(_ => true)`. This will be equivalent to `size`, just less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using `span`,

```
def encode(xs: List[Symbol]): List[(Int,Symbol)] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: xss => val (g,rest) = xs.span(_ == x)
                   (g.size,g.head) +: encode(rest) 
}
```

where we bisect the list into identical items to the head first, and then the rest.